# Need to execute command via jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

I have a scenario where I need to use jmeter to run numerous Kubectl commands via jmeter
os sampler snippet: tried to execute `kubectl get pods` but still not been through,
[OS sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeLnL.png)

getting the response as -- 'kubectl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

[OS sampler response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m7AY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that `kubectl` command is not on your Windows system [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)), add it there and restart JMeter.

Otherwise you can provide the [full path to kubectl](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001708.htm)

Also be aware that [k8s has REST API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.27/) so it might worth considering switching to [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers, see [REST API Testing: How to Do it Right](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/rest-api-testing) article for more information.